# API not accepting ruby hash converted to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a ruby hash I need to provide to an API as JSON but it won't get accepted and throws an error.

```
params = {"eventIds" =>
    ["client.created", "client.updated", "client.deactivated"], 
    "eventSchemaVersion"=>1
}
```

When I call `params.to_json` I get:

```
"{\"eventIds\":[\"client.created\",\"client.updated\",\"client.deactivated\"],\"eventSchemaVersion\":1"}"
```

and when I provide that as the body of my request I get a 400 error.  The api instructs to provide the body as follows:

```
request.body = "{requestBody}"

{
  "eventIds" : [
    "classSchedule.created",
    "classSchedule.updated",
    "classSchedule.cancelled"
  ],
  "eventSchemaVersion" : 1
}
```

I simply included in my request: `request.body = params.to_json`.

**Edit:** 
Here is my full request:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://mb-api.mindbodyonline.com/push/api/v1/subscriptions")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["api-key"] = ENV['API_KEY']
request["content-type"] = 'application/json'

params = {"eventIds" =>
           ["client.created", "client.updated", "client.deactivated"], 
           "eventSchemaVersion"=>1
         }
request.body = params.to_json

response = http.request(request)
```

Any ideas on how to improve this?

Comment: Could you please share the headers of the request?

Comment: `request.body = "{requestBody}"` looks really strange and is not valid JSON. Did you mean to do string interpolation `request.body = "#{requestBody}"`?

Comment: Also how are you sending the request to the API? I'm guessing this is simple a double encoding issue where you are passing a JSON string and the API client is also doing JSON conversion.

Comment: @max I actually copied that directly from the docs: https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/WebhooksDocumentation#post-subscription

Comment: @max I am sending it using NET::HTTP

Comment: Please add the code where you are using the converted json and making the api call.? that will help to identify the issue.

Comment: I've added the full call